# Removable singularity equivalence proposition,complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Say we have an analytic f in a deleted neighbourhood of z0. Then f has a removable singularity(defined as the b coefficients of its laurent series are all zero) if and only if f can be extended to z0 so that it is analytic at z0.
The => direction is easy.How is the <= direction proven?
I am studying Marsden Hoffman which says it is obvious and gives no proof.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Even simpler than the given answer: if the function is analytic then it has a power series (in the sense of Laurent series) with only positive terms, so the negative terms of the Laurent series must be zero by the uniqueness of power series.

Comment: Oh yes indeed. From the taylor theorem.

Comment: I think it is a good remark. If one assumes the uniqueness then it becomes easier, but I think the integration method is more complex-analytic spirit.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure why this works out. You have two separate series on the one side of the equality and the taylor one on the other side. And the second one is not a classic power series form it has (z-z0)^n is on the denominator. From the theorem I know, that's described in this book, you can equalize the coefficients only if you have two power series of the form an(z-z0)^n. Anyway I solved my problem from Riemann's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it has analytic extension, $$b_n = \oint_C\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{-n+1}}dz = 0$$ by Cauchy's integral formula(note for $n\ge 1$, the integrand is still analytic).

Comment: Thanks, it was obvious indeed.